# i have three response like (/banner),(/latest),(/popular)and i want to send in one api called home

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to node js and mongo db. I want to send three different response API in single API. Like

```
[router.get(/banner), router.get(/latest), router.get(/popular)]
```

I want like this response

```
[Banner Api Response + Latest  Api Response + Popular  Api Response]=home api
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling endpoints from another endpoints has several drawbacks. You can read from [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/345406/is-it-bad-design-to-internally-call-api-endpoints-from-within-the-api-instance).

You can create functions and call it from various endpoints. For example,

You create functions for banner, Latest, Popular API endpoints.

/banner -> call the function created for banner endpoint

/latest -> call the function created for latest endpoint

/popular -> call the function created for popular endpoint

/home -> call all those 3 functions and return the response in the way you want to.